# Save/create a list of structs to Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a struct that I want to save to Firebase. I want to add/create a list of structs in Firebase. How would I do this and be able to retrieve `n` of these items sorted by the score property?

```
struct HighScoreItem {
    var username: String = ""
    var score: Int = 0
    var date: Date = Date()
}
```

Comment: You have problem with `how to save?` or `how to query for n numbers sorted by score?`

Answer (score 3):

I think you must wrap your struct as a property list.

First add a function for converting your struct into a property list like the following:

```
struct HighScoreItem {
  var username: String = ""
  var score: Int = 0
  var date: Date = Date()

  init(from dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    username = dictionary["username"] as! String
    score = dictionary["score"] as! Int
    date = dictionary["date"] as! Date
  }

  func asPropertyList() -> [String: Any] {
    return ["username": username, "score": score, "date", date]
  }

}
```

later where you want to upload it to firebase:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let highScore = HighScoreItem()
ref.child("HighScores").child("0").setValue(highScore.asPropertyList())
```

And to read the value

```
ref.child("HighScores").child("0").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
  let value = snapshot.value as? Dictionary
  let highScore = HighScoreItem.init(from: value)
  print(highScore)

  // ...
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```